# sticky navbar jQuery not working in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky navbar using jQuery and it works perfectly fine on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/xXJNbR). However I'm now adding it to my html/js files and its not longer working properly. The only difference I have between my CodePen and my files is that I have [Particleground](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground) in my first section(as shown on CodePen). So my javascript file looks like this:

```
// particleground
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 particleground(document.getElementById('particles'), {
  dotColor: '#E5E8E8',
  lineColor: '#E5E8E8',
  density: 5500
 });
 var intro = document.getElementById('intro');
 intro.style.marginTop = - intro.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
}, false);

//sticky navbar
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var $navbar = $("#navbar"),
    y_pos = $navbar.offset().top,
    height = $navbar.height();

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > y_pos + height) {
        $navbar.addClass("navbar-fixed").animate({
            top: 0
        });
    } else if (scrollTop <= y_pos) {
        $navbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed").clearQueue().animate({
            top: "-48px"
        }, 0);
    }
});

})(jQuery, undefined);
```

My HTML header is in this order:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.particleground.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.particleground.js"></script>
```

When I run the page, the Particleground is working fine but the scroll bar doesn't move anymore like the one in my CodePen. Is the issue because I have particleground and the stick navbar in my js file? I'm not sure what the problem is and how would I fix this?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: see console log, might the error in your js